# Saving HashMaps using a file path

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I have a simple data problem that I want to solve. The program creates a generated button and asks you to name it. It then saves that info to a `HashMap` of type `<String, Fragment>` and spawns the button. I created a file directory so that it saves the `HashMap` so when you exit out and go back, the buttons will still be there. I haven't figured out how to get it working and right now it only saves one button and discards the rest. Any help would be appreciated! Right now, some of my file stuff is messed up because I was testing stuff and nothing seemed to work.

How can I save the `HashMap` to a file when you leave the page, and retrieve the `HashMap` when you go back to the page?

Code for adding the buttons:

```
mLayout.addView(createNewTextView(newCataLine));

Fragment quotesFragment = QuotesFragment.newInstance();
cataFragmentMap.put(newCataLine, quotesFragment);

try {
    outputStream = getContext().openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    ObjectOutputStream oout = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);
    oout.writeObject(cataFragmentMap);
    oout.close();

} catch (Exception ex) {
    Log.d("HELLO",ex.toString());
}
```

Code for creating the buttons:

```
private TextView createNewTextView(String text) {
    final LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams =
            new 
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    final Button cataButton = new Button(getContext());
    cataButton.setAllCaps(false);
    cataButton.setTextSize(40);
    cataButton.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    cataButton.setText(text);

    cataButton.setOnClickListener(cataButtonOnClick());

    return cataButton;
}
```

Code for getting the file:

```
File directory = getContext().getFilesDir();
    File file = new File(directory, filename);
    mLayout.addView(createNewTextView(*file*));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will allow you to use `ObjectInputStream` to store the `HashMap` in a file and then retrieve it using `ObjectInputStream`:

```
try {
    File mapFile = new File(getDir("storage", MODE_PRIVATE), "hashmap");
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(mapFile));
    oos.writeObject(hashmap);
    oos.flush();
    oos.close();

    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(mapFile));
    HashMap map = (HashMap)ois.readObject();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Handle exception here
}
```

Comment: How do I add the buttons using this info?

Comment: Well, if you want to save the buttons so that the next time you open a `Fragment` you get the same buttons back, you should maybe make your `HashMap` have the type `<String, ArrayList<Button>>` and then the next time you create a `Fragment`, just use the list of `Button`s and add them to it.